# How to type a document in LATEX

Tags: thesis, online, resources

So, I completed my masters from a poor country and there was no one to tell ( including my advisor) to write masters thesis in LATEX.

I wrote my thesis in MS word.

I am now applying to West for PhD and I want to type my thesis again in LATEX. But, don't know how.

I use Math Stackexchange and can comfortably type the questions in TEX.  The website shows the output of TEX formulas but how will typing in LATEX convert to a pdf document of mathematical symbols by itself like word? ( All of tex for this site was learned from this page by me: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

There might be few others questions as well.

Basically, I want to learn about LATEX from the start so as to type my thesis again in it.

> Can you please refer me to some online resources  from which I can learn LATEX  it from start ?

Comment: Start here: https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/lshort/english/

Comment: see https://www.learnlatex.org/ which has a tutorial in several languages

Comment: The guide suggested by DG is a very good starting resource. Once you can write simple documents, you can read the (intro chapters) of the documentation of specialized packages for your particular needs (need to show some code? Listings or minted are great. Need to make a pretty drawing? TikZ is excellent). TeX is much more than typing equations! It's a great journey

Comment: In this site there are thousand of small reproducible examples of almost everything that LaTeX can do. Many are to show to do  something  bizarre, with enigmatic complex code  that you will never need, but man others are  practical examples of how to do all document structures that  you will need (tables, figures, footnotes,  table of contents, headers, etc.). To start the thesis you only have to learn to make a "hello world" document and then add what you learn of these basic and easy to understand examples, but always remember the KISS principle, the best principle never ever stated.

Comment: It is silly that many of the beginner manuals mentioned LaTeX on pdfTeX as standard, i.e mentioned `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` as needed in the preamble. Of course, there are exceptions, for example lshort doesn't say nothing til 2.5 where the existence of LuaLaTeX and fontspec/polyglossia is mentioned. Beginners don't need to use LaTeX over pdfTeX today, they don't want to dig to the 8bit fonts problems, they don't want to use nothing like `\Euro` etc. (2.4.5 2.4.6 in lshort) when we can write simply €. They don't want to tarry with table 2.2. Beginners are lost right at the beginning.:)